# add view to vertical linearlayout inside horizontallscrollview within scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I want to programatically add viwes to vertical orientation linearlayout within horizontalscrollview within Scrollview. Basic scheme of my layout is belowe:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- same header code -->

    </LinearLaout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

     </HorizontalScrollView>



</ScrollView>
```

Now if i'm adding programatically 5 views to list_view linearlayout, i get only one view, and free sapce below it. If i comment HorizontallScrollView like that:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- same header code -->

    </LinearLaout>


        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>



</ScrollView>
```

All views are show correct, but they aren't horizontall scrollable. Please give me same ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: ScrollView allows only one child ... you're adding 2. That layout will not work

Comment: I think scroll view doesn't allow more than one child.check this once.

Comment: I agree with @gunar and @"Suresh Kumar Reddy Dangatla" that this layout scheme is wrong, but in my project in scrollview i have linearlayout which consits of LinearLayout(@+id/header) and HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to change linearlayout's android:layout_width attribute to wrap_content within horizontalScrollview

Comment: Thank you so much . good technical point . in now i could to have vertical linearlayout inside of horizontalscrollview .